# How to change the resource background color of TextView?

Tags: java, android

I want to change drawable picture color of TextView(background) but I tried this code without success:

```
textView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(listMap.get((int)position)
.get("color").toString()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

I'm getting this error:

> The method parseColor(String) is undefined for the type String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Just checked it in android studio and it works fine):

```
val myBackgroundColor =  Color.parseColor(listMap.get((int)position).get("color").toString())
textView.setBackgroundColor(myBackgroundColor)
```

If it doesn't work, I guess it means thatthe color value you are getting from your listMap is not a proper hex value like `#00FF00`.

Check and make sure it is in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

what's the string received from this ?

```
listMap.get((int)position).get("color").toString()
```

I think this function just return the number of the color, you also need the "#"

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are:

```
#RRGGBB
#AARRGGBB
```

[acording to Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color)

Comment: thanks for answer; the ListMap have content of List JSON (key, value) among the keys ther's the color for every position like this [{"color":"#F44336"}]
every thing have it's color, so i want to set the color in every position according to its color from listMap key "color"